# No entiendo como mostrar disponibilidad de un grupo de variables

Tags: python

```
# Importacion de Librerias
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
import getpass
import os
os.system ("cls")

#Declaramos las variables

registeredUser = ('DrakiSama','SnowBear','Invitado')
registeredPW = ('password')

#Declaramos las funciones
def login(usuario,passw):
    if usuario in registeredUser:
        if passw in registeredPW:
            return 1
        else:
            print("\n\tLa contraseña no coincide..\n")
    else:
        return 2

 #Iniciamos los procesos
usuario=input('Usuario: ')
passw = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

if login(usuario,passw)==1:
    print('Bienvenido',usuario)
else:
    print('ERROR! Usuario no registrado.')

#Variables departamentos A
A1="L"
A2="L"
A3="L"
A4="L"
A5="L"
A6="L"
A7="L"
A8="L"
A9="L"
A10="L"
#Variables departamentos B
B1="L"
B2="L"
B3="L"
B4="L"
B5="L"
B6="L"
B7="L"
B8="L"
B9="L"
B10="L"
#Variables departamentos C
C1="L"
C2="L"
C3="L"
C4="L"
C5="L"
C6="L"
C7="L"
C8="L"
C9="L"
C10="L"
#Variables departamentos D
D1="L"
D2="L"
D3="L"
D4="L"
D5="L"
D6="L"
D7="L"
D8="L"
D9="L"
D10="L"
# Mostramos el menu en pantalla
print("""
    1) Comprar Departamento                    3) Ver Listado de compradores
    2) Mostrar departamentos disponibles       4) Buscar comprador
    5) Reasignar compra                        6) Mostrar Ganancias totales

                                 7) Salir...
    """)

# Vemos que ingreso el usuario
eligio=input("-Seleccione algo : ")

# Y segun la opcion que ingreso se hace un codigo diferente
if eligio=="1":
    print("""
             ____________TIPO____________
            |____|__A__|__B__|__C__|__D__|
            |_10_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__9_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__8_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__7_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__6_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__5_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__4_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__3_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__2_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|
            |__1_|__L__|__L__|__L__|__L__|


        Digite el departamento solicitado: """)
    p=input("Digite tecla para seguir")



elif eligio=="2":
    x = 3
    y = 5
    print("x * y = ", x * y)
elif eligio=="3":
    print("Creo que hace frío")
elif eligio=="4":
    print("otra opción")
elif eligio=="5":
    print("otra opción")
elif eligio=="6":
    print("otra opción")
elif eligio=="7":
    print("Adios!")



else:
    print("Opción no válida")
```

---

El sistema debe solicitar al cliente el departamento a comprar. Existen 4
departamentos por piso. En el piso 1, se encuentra el departamento tipo A, B, C y D y lo mismo se replica
para el resto de los pisos, por ejemplo: si un cliente compra el departamento A en el piso 9, sería A9. Se debe
ingresar el piso en que se adquirirá el departamento y el tipo. Se debe validar que estén dentro de los rangos
válidos. El sistema tiene en pantalla los departamentos disponibles, donde aparecerán con X los
departamentos ya vendidos.

Aparte tengo problemas con el login ya que se puede saltar...

Comment: Plantéate reescribir todo usando una lista de diccionarios. En la lista, cada elemento es un piso, y el diccionario tendrá como claves las letras de los departamentos. Así por ejemplo `lista[0]["A"]` sería el piso 1, departamento A. Inicializa cada uno con "L", y escribe una función que recorra la lista para crear el gráfico ASCII que muestra el estado. Modificar el estado sería tan sencillo como `lista[piso-1][depto]="X"`

Comment: Para evitar que el programa se ejecute a pesar de haber fallado la contraseña, debes poner un `quit()` en el `else` , tras el `print('ERROR! Usuario no registrado.')`